# storing url rewrite mappings in a separate file using Tuckey?

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am attempting to store URL rewrite mappings in a separate file.

I found some answers for using .Net or Apache, but had no luck for how to do this using Tuckey in Tomcat.

Does anyone know if Tuckey supports this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The **urlrewrite.xml** path may be modified in the filter configuration.

It may be done in the **WEB-INF/web.xml** file, by altering the **confPath** param value :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- if you need to the conf file path can be changed
         it is specified as a path relative to the root of your context
         (default /WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml) -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Documentation here : http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#filterparams

Answer (score 0):

I looks like **Tuckey** supports a separate **urlrewrite.xml**.

See [Configuration File WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I actually found the answer from http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#mod_rewrite_conf (scroll down to the very end).  RewriteMap  Not supported

Comment: You should post your own answer. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/